# Getting data from database and inserting into JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a javascript file that has local variables named , with some data in quotation marks , for example, 'name' , '123 lane' , and etc. I want the variable to get data from a database and not the plaintext. How do I enter the code to do this in my JavaScript variable ?

Comment: Kindly Elaborate your problem further more details with code

Comment: *"I want the variable to get data from a database"*: sounds like you are looking for [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX).

Comment: I need to pull data from my database and insert it into a variable called locations, it looks something like this

Comment: ['Name', '716-123-4567', 'lat', 'long']; and ect @jsve

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how often you want the content to be updated. If you are only wanting to get the content once when the page loads try this php code:

```
<?php
$address = array('1234','green ave', 'burlingame', 'ca', 'add more values here if you want');

echo '<script type="text/Javascript">var myVariable = []; '.for($i = 0; $i != count($address); $i++)
{
echo 'myVariable.push('.$address[$i].');';
}
.'</script>';
?>
```

Let me know if that works for the array transition. I have no way to test it right now since I'm on my iPod touch.

Here is some documentation about php's mysqli functions; http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp .

I've never worked with google maps in this way. I'm not in the position to help you figure out the google maps end of the question. This is about as much as I can help you.

Comment: So this is how I insert data from my database into my JavaScript variable? @www139

Comment: Put that in the top of the head section of the page.

Comment: Can you explain what this means phpVarWithYourDatabaseValue @www139

Comment: So basically something like this: <?php echo '<script type="text/Javascript">var locations = '.$db = SELECT * FROM Table_name.';</script>'; ?>. Is that right? @www139

Comment: Yes, php and simple SQL in MySQL @www139

Comment: I don't know if you know how to do this, but I am trying to get a Google map to insert data from my database into the map using JavaScript and php, but I am stuck for the moment, can you help me out? @www139

Comment: You may want to add that to your question description. I've never worked with google maps in php so I'm not a good resource for that part of the question. If you have already figured out some code please post that. Nobody really understands what you are asking. It looks like you are trying to store an address into a php array. I'll post the code for the php array to javascript array code....

Comment: Well thanks for trying, I am also 15 years old..  I love to make websites!! @www139 ps: Hunter

Comment: Wow that's neat! Are you homeschooled? It's amazing, I've met already two other people who are 15!

Comment: As far as figuring this question out, I think if you edit it and make your question more clear people will understand what you are asking. :)

Comment: No I go to a public school in Ny learned same way you did. If you want we can chat via SMS.  I can tell you how I learned.  @www139

Comment: I don't feel comfortable leaving my phone number on a public question. My email address is wwww13455@gmail.com (I know my email address is weird but don't fear :-D)